# How would I receive and send information to console in a different program in Java?

Tags: java, console-application

How would I receive and send information to console in a different program in Java? The program I am trying to receive console from was made in [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/). I don't know if that makes a difference. I have been reading up on different topics, but all seem to be telling me for the program that is asking for it. I currently don't have any code of this because of lack of information about the topic. Thank your for you help and time if you can help me.

Comment: Look at [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) - is this what you're after? (After re-reading your question, perhaps not -- I'll leave this here anyway).

Comment: Please write for readers whether **game console** or the more traditional **command line console**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an OS-specific kind of question...  How to pipe standard output from one process to the standard input in another process...

Unix normally does it with the pipe symbol (|) as in:

```
$ ls | wc
```

This takes the output from ls and sends it to the input of wc...
If this info is not helpful, consider expanding your question and making it more specific.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well I have tried to get a program from [task manager] and in speak latch onto it and receive console that way, but the code didn't seem to work and tried many different ways. I found it useless and decided to get a new way of doing it.